# Does Python Use Threads by Default?

Tags: python, multithreading

When I write a code using python I always wonder if `python` uses multithreading by default or not.

Assuming a code such as

```
l = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
print reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
```

Will be done easily using multithreading processes. By letting threads to get the sum of a small collection of the list.

In short, does python use multithreading by default , and when it possible or not? Or always use one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without explicitly defining threading behavior, Python doesn't use other threads. Further, threading in Python isn't always fully functional because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) as the interpreter's memory handling isn't thread safe.

Comment: Some implementations of Python don't use a GIL

Comment: +1, there are other versions besides CPython, though that's the "standard".

Answer (score 1):

No. Your code will run sequentially.

Additionally your example is relying on your knowledge of the associative property of addition with integers.

Python doesn't know it's a list of integers or that addition will be associative for the objects you are adding.

In particular, if your list is a list of floats, the order you add them up *can* affect the result